# How can I know how many matches I have between two arrays (one nested inside an object)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I need to know how many matches I have between people.compare array and names array, then create a new object including this data.

```
names = [ 'Juan', 'Old']

people = [
  {compare: ['Juan', 'Old'], Age: 70},
  {compare: ['Juan', 'Young'], Age: 20}
]
```

Expected output:

```
peopleNew = [
  {compare: ['Juan', 'Old'], 'Age': 70, 'MATCHES': 2},
  {compare: ['Juan', 'Young'], 'Age': 20, 'MATCHES': 1}
]
```

Comment: `const peopleNew = people.map(({compare, Age}) => ({compare, Age, MATCHES: compare.filter(v => names.includes(v)).length}));`

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code loops through each array and uses Array.includes() to check each item for equality:

```
const peopleNew = people.map(obj => {
  let matches = 0;
  
  obj.compare.forEach(name => {
    if (names.includes(name)) {
      matches++; // Increase count by 1
    }
  })
  
  // Create new object from original with new 'matches' property
  return Object.assign({}, obj, { matches });
});
```